# Spring Roo & JSON: Define array based operations for delete, update,

Tags: arrays, json, spring, curl, spring-roo

I implemented a webservice with roo. All queries run fine.

Delete:
I miss a automatic generated method to delete multiple id/version pairs at once. A call could look like this:

```
curl -i -X DELETE -H Content-Type:application/json -d [{"id":1,"version":0},{"id":2,"version":0}] http://.../objects
```

Update:
I also miss an update method for many entries. Call could look the same as above but with the fields to update added and "-X PUT".

```
curl -i -X PUT -H Content-Type:application/json 
 -d [{"id":1,"version":0,"value":"new1"},{"id":2,"version":0,"value":"new2"}] http://.../objects
```

Insert:
Is there a way to get the id's or the contents back after I inserted an new object with json?
When I define the "Accept:application/json" header I get an empty response.

I rather want roo to update this methods then write my own, since there are many fields I would have to maintain. Otherwise roo would be useless.

Are there any templates I could adopt for my needs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking, but you can absolutely do normal REST methods using JSON.  As for retrieving JSON, you can do that too.  There is an annotation, I believe its @ResponseBody, that you tack on the front of your MVC method to tell Spring "my response will contain plain-text, not instructions on which template to return", then you just use the JSON methods on the Entities to output JSON.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and misunderstanding my question. I looked for a code generator that creates the REST code by itself.

Comment: I would look at Spring Roo.  It does some really nice auto-code generation, and packages most of its generated code as Aspects, and can easily be used to generate a fully working project then remove all the Roo-isms.